# Python split function to extract the first element and last element

Tags: python

```
  python code --> ",".join("one_two_three".split("_")[0:-1])
```

I want to take the 0th element and last element of delimited string and create a new string put of it . The code should delimited  string of any length

```
Expected output : "one,three"
```

The above code gives me

```
   'one,two'
```

Can some one  please help me

Comment: The `[0:-1]` slice means 'from the 1st element to the penultimate one'; you want something like:  `",".join(((mylist := "one_two_three".split("_"))[0], mylist[-1]))` or `(mylist :="one_two_three".split("_"))[0] + ', ' + mylist[-1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[0:-1]` is a slice, it returns all the elements from 0 to the 2nd-to-last element.

Without the third `stride` parameter, which is used for getting every Nth element, a slice can only return a contiguous portion of a list, not two separate items.

You should select the first and last separately, then concatenate them.

```
items = "one_two_three".split("_")
result = f"{items[0]},{items[-1]}"
```

Comment: *"A slice can only return a contiguous portion of a list, not two separate items"* A slice can have a step other than 1, and so return non-contiguous items. I don't think I'd actually do this, but `x[0: len(x): len(x)-1]` is equivalent to `[x[0], x[-1]]`

Comment: I've updated the answer to mention strides. While that can be corrupted for this purpose, it's not really what it's for.

Answer (score 3):

Assign the relevant parts to variables and use them:

```py
first, *_, last = "one_two_three_four".split("_")
```

Comment: This won't get the first and last if there are more than 3 items.

Comment: `first, *_, last = "one_two_three_four".split("_")` will though

Answer (score 2):

`operator.itemgetter` gives another way of getting the first (0) and last (-1) items in a single statement:

```
from operator import itemgetter
s = "one,two,three"

res = ",".join(itemgetter(0, -1)(s.split(",")))
print(res)
```

gives:

```
one,three
```

Comment: Good to know it can be achieved like you did, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The slice you've written, `[0:-1]`, means all the items in the list except the last one, which is what you're getting.

Assuming there can be any number of items, here's no straightforward way to get the first and last items in a single expression. Instead, split the list into a separate variable, and get the desired items that way.

```
items = "one_two_three".split("_")
",".join([items[0], items[-1]])
```

You could do this in one line via the "walrus" operator `:=`, but it's kinda ugly and difficult to understand:

```
",".join([(items := "one_two_three".split("_"))[0], items[-1]])
```